# Interface-less .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, windows, outlook, vsto

I'm building a VSTO Outlook add in in .NET (C#).

I need to start a new separate project that interacts with this add-in and with some local computer feature's (wireless connection, windows credentials, system threading, etc).

There is no need for building forms or any kind of windows user interface.

My question is what is the most suitable project within all .NET project templates for my situation?

Comment: It's hard to say, but I think a console app would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a class library (assembly) is the best option for you. See [Build a .NET Standard library with C# and the .NET Core SDK in Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio) for more information.

However, it depends on where your library is used besides the add-in project.

Comment: To sum up, the main purpose of this parallel proyect is to reallocate all processing consumption away from the outlook application. For example, we are now managing a polling interaction with SQL Server within our outlook add-in and it crashes while the client is offline. I know this can be solved by changing to a data base pushing system notification. Nevertheless there are and there will be  more other High consuming processes to deal with in the future and i will ultimately need to get all these processes separated from Outlook in order for us not to crash it.

Comment: Yeah, a class library works best for such scenarios.